# Maximizing sequences

Tags: inequality

What is the maximum value of

$x_1x_2 +x_3x_4 + ... x_7x_8$

if  $x_1+x_2... +x_8 = 8$

I tried using Cauchy-Schwarz

$(x_1 + x_2 .. +x_7)(x_2 +x_3 ... +x_8)= (\sqrt{x_1x_2} +... \sqrt{x_7x_8})$

$=(8-x_8)(8-x_1)$

Where I am stuck. The answer is really easy to guess but I do not know a good solution.

Comment: Are you trying to maximise $x_1x_2 +x_3x_4 +  x_5x_6+  x_7x_8$ with each variable non-negative and their sum $8$?  If so, the first step might be to maximise  $x_1x_2$ with each variable non-negative and their sum $y_1$

Comment: Can you please stop posting the same "maximize this expression" questions? You are showing barely any attemtps and are not paying attention to the answers people give you

Comment: sorry for being stupid, i wont delete the post since i really do not know how to answer the problem, I have understood the solution you have given me. You dont really have to answer the problem.

Comment: I am completely fine with people posting questions - my problem is that you are not showing your work (1 sentence is not too much work, you know), you are posting the same type of questions over and over again and you are not contributing back in  any way by accepting/upvoting/trying to understand better. I am more than happy to help if I can - but I just don't like this type of behaviour